# Probablity Calculation

Tags: probability, self-study

So, to be honest, I have not figured out how to calculate the probability of the following problem:

> Knowing a species has a 20% probability to be sick, and amoung the sick subjects there is a probability of 60% to be young subjects and a 40% of adults.
>   In the same species, there is a 80% probability to not be sick, and amoung the healthy subjects, there is a probability of 80% to be a young subject and 20% to be an adult subject.
>
> The problem is; If an adult is found, what is the probability of the adult of being sick.

I thought it could work out with the P(A)*P(B) rule, but doesn't seem to be working since the result is 33.3%.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, consider adding the self-study tag.

Comment: @StefanJorgensen Yes! Done it. Didn't know I could do that or had to do that, thanks!

Comment: When you say the "probability of having an adult subject which is sick", do you mean the probability that a subject is sick, given that the subject is an adult? These are somewhat different questions, and the answer to the latter should be 33%

Comment: @StefanJorgensen Yeah, that's it!! Re-edited the question. How do you calculate that?

Comment: This Q has the `[self-study]` tag & what the OP thought / tried. It meets our standards; I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: Look into marginal probabilities. Here you want to marginalize the variable which says whether a subject is sick for adult specimen. This is done as @StefanJorgensen described by summing all conditional probabilities, i.e. sick and healthy, given for adults.

Comment: Drawing a diagram embodying the information in the question might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the probability that the subject is sick, given that they are an adult. First, calculate the probability that an adult subject is sick (which is the $P(\text{sick})P(\text{adult}\mid \text{sick})$ rule you tried earlier), but since you already know the subject is an adult, you need to divide by the probability that the subject is an adult, which is $P(\text{sick})P(\text{adult}\mid\text{sick}) + P(\text{healthy})P(\text{adult}\mid \text{healthy})$.